# Swift intersect multiple array

Tags: arrays, intersection

I have an array of array, the size is dynamic, I want to find the common element in A.

> A = [ [1,2,3], [2,4,6,1], [3,6,2,1], [1,1,1],.. ].

> For above Array A the common element is 1

how do I achieve in an efficient way? I can loop and find but I want to know the most efficient solution?

Comment: Can you give some sample inputs and outputs? Also, please show what you have tried s far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given an array of arrays

```
let lists = [[1,2,3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

You can find the common elements writing

```
let firstList = lists.first ?? []

let commonElements = lists.reduce(Set(firstList)) { (result, list)  in
    result.intersection(list)
}
```

Result

```
print(commonElements) // [3]
```

Comment: Note that this will unnecessarily compute an intersection of the first array with itself. Depending on the use case, you could do `lists.dropFirst().reduce(Set(...`. Otherwise, excellent answer!